# Show that each of the $35$-roots of unity is the cube of some root of $35$th degree of unity.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

After showing that the $n$-roots of unity form a multiplicative group I'm asked the following:

> Show that each of the $35$-roots of unity is the cube of some root of $35$th
>   degree of unity.

I don't have idea how to start with this problem. I'm only able to sort of formalize what the problem is asking me to prove, that is:

> Let $(\mathbb{C}^{35}, \cdot)$ be the group of the $35$-roots of
>   unity. Then I have to show that $\forall a \in \mathbb{C}^{35}\
> \exists\ b \in \mathbb{C}^{35}: b = a^3$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean, $b^3=a$.

Comment: Did you find the notation $\Bbb C^{35}$ in a book? It's not exactly standard (not for this anyway).

Comment: @ArnaudD. What is the standard? I don't know honestly.

Comment: I don't know if there is really a standard notation for subgroups of roots of $1$, but $\Bbb C^{n}$ usually denotes the cartesian product of $n$ copies of $\Bbb C$, so it's a bit weird to see it used like you do.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Ok. Thanks for pointing that out. I'll be more careful with that.

Comment: Given $a$ such that $a^{35}=1$. Set $b=a^{12}$. Then $b^3=a^{36} = a^{35}\cdot a = 1\cdot a =a$. And note that $b^{35} = (a^{12})^{35} = (a^{35})^{12} = 1^{12} = 1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$b=e^{\frac{2n\pi i}{35}}$ for some $n\in\{1,2,\dots,35\}$.

Then you are looking for $a=e^{\frac{2m\pi i}{35}}$, with $3m\equiv n, \mod35$.

There is always a solution to this since $3$ and $35$ are coprime.

Comment: I'll just add that $3^{-1}=12, \mod35$, so choosing $m=12n$ will give the desired $a$.

Answer (score 2):

Your formulation is not correct : what you have written is that the cube of any $35$-root is again a $35$-root. The correct formulation is $\forall a \in \mathbb{C}^{35} \exists\ b \in \mathbb{C}^{35}: a = b^3$.

As for the solution :

**Hint :** for all $a\in \Bbb C^{35}$, $a^{35}=1$, and thus $a^{36}=a$.